# Press and Release behavior for Buttons in Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, button

I want to have "press" and "release" behavior for a button in my windows form. How can this be achieved? To be more clear, one click of a button should result in "press and hold" state and the next click should "release" it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CheckBox:

```
checkBox1.Appearance = Button;
```

The graphic quality might vary.